# Merge multiple rows into a single one in Access table with unique ID value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table which goes:

```
ID | Name | Relationship
123 | Jane Smith  | Wife
123 | Bruce Smith | Child
```

and so on...

I want to create a table where people with the same ID reside in the same row:

```
ID  | 1st_Name | Relationship | 2nd_Name | Relationship
123 | Jane Smith | Wife | Bruce Smith | Child
```

I do have a field which indicates the number of incidence of each ID i.e.

```
ID | CountofID
123 | 2
123 | 2
456 | 3
456 | 3
456 | 3
```

Not sure if that will help.

Someone suggested to use DCount and a function to produce Row Numbers.
https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/140703-row-number/
Not sure how to proceed. Is there a way to generate a DCount only For Each unique ID and then loop and reset it for every new ID? i.e. 1-4 for ID 123, then 1-3 for ID 456, etc.?

Are there other ways to go about this in Access?

Anything to point me to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Note: I asked in other sites and they took notice of how wrong the structure is of the table. The goal isn't about data structure. I want to merge multiple rows into a single one automatically, because I had to do it manually through Excel sheets.

Comment: Pretty sure msaccess calls this a crosstab query.  [Example](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8)  Pivot in enterprise databases.  However, Access doesn't require the dynamic SQL which Enterprise DBs do.

Comment: Given the sketchy support of pivots in Access, if all you need to do is get these into a spreadsheet like that, you'd probably do better automating the Excel side.

Comment: Is there a `123 | Bob Smith  | Self` record? What does the `Wife` point to in `123 | Jane Smith  | Wife`?

Comment: Write some VBA code to loop through your table per ID. Not sure why your want to store the output in a table, are there any specific reasons for that? How about writing the output to a txt file?

Comment: @Brad There is one but they're INNER JOIN'd ON the field ID, thus the output is multiple Bob Smith rows with the corresponding relative